# How can I display unicode emoticons in Chrome/ Safari?

Tags: html, google-chrome, unicode, utf-8, safari

I'm building a Chat with PHP & JS.
I'm trying to display the following unicode characters in Google Chrome: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Smileys

The characters are displayed correctly in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome/ Safari.
The characterset is UTF-8.

Any ideas?

Comment: My bet is that's a font issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known defect with Chrome on OSX: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62435

Comment: I think it's fixed now. (U+1F360: ROASTED SWEET POTATO)

Comment: Not yet. I see a square box in Chrome/40.0.2214.111

Comment: I've got 41.0.2272.53.  Maybe this is fixed in the beta channel, and coming soon to release.